# Error while calling function through C DLL

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I have a DLL in which the following is the header and .c file:

```
//demo.h
#define vers 0x1
__declspec export void getversion(ulong * version);

//demo.c
#include"demo.h"
void getversion(ulong * version)
{
*version=(ulong)vers;
}
```

The python script that I had written for calling the DLL using ctypes is as below:

```
//python script
import ctypes 
import sys
from ctypes import *
vers=0x1
def getversion(version):
    mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary('demo.dll')
    mydll.getversion.argtypes=[POINTER(c_ulong)]
    mydll.getversion.restype=None
    mydll.getversion(version) 

version=c_ulong()
print("Version=",version.value)
```

But the value of the version that I'm getting is 0. 
The output should be 1 instead.
Can anyone help me with the following code? I don't know where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't see the header included.

Comment: Ohh ya , the header is included in the .c file. I missed writing it here. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't calling `getversion`.  Your code creates a default `ulong()` (which is initialized to zero) and printing it.

```
version=c_ulong()
print("Version=",version.value)
```

Here's working code:

```
from ctypes import *

mydll = CDLL('demo.dll')
mydll.getversion.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ulong)]
mydll.getversion.restype = None

version=c_ulong()
mydll.getversion(byref(version)) # call function with address of version
print("Version=",version.value)
```

Here's the DLL I tested with (yours as is won't compile...no definition of `ulong`) and compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void getversion(unsigned long* version)
{
    *version = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is this what you should do:

```
mydll = cdll.demo  # just a simpler way to load the dll, not the solution yet
ver = c_ulong()
mydll.getversion(byref(ver))
print(ver.value)
```

Comment: This didn't work.The error I'm getting is that: "func = self.__getitem__(name) " and also "func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))"  due to the line- mydll.getversion(byref(ver)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully working example for windows&vs, if you wanna try on linux you just need to change your datatypes and get rid of the windows headers:

**demo.h**

```
#include <windows.h>

ULONG g_version = 0x3;

__declspec(dllexport) void set_version(ULONG version);
__declspec(dllexport) ULONG get_version();
__declspec(dllexport) void get_version_by_reference(ULONG* version);
```

**demo.c**

```
// build: cl.exe /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL demo.c /link /DLL /OUT:demo.dll
#include "demo.h"

void set_version(ULONG version) {
    g_version=version;
}

ULONG get_version() {
    return g_version;
}

void get_version_by_reference(ULONG* version) {
    *version=(ULONG)g_version;
}
```

**demo.py**

```
import ctypes
import sys
from ctypes import *

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('demo.dll')

# __declspec(dllexport) void set_version(ULONG version);
mydll.set_version.restype = None
mydll.set_version.argtypes = [c_ulong]

# __declspec(dllexport) void get_version();
mydll.get_version.restype = c_ulong
mydll.get_version.argtypes = []

# __declspec(dllexport) void get_version_by_reference(ULONG* version);
mydll.get_version_by_reference.restype = None
mydll.get_version_by_reference.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ulong)]

print "Step1, testing get_version"
print '-'*80
print mydll.get_version()
print "\nStep2, testing set_version & get_version"
print '-'*80
mydll.set_version(c_ulong(0x05))
print mydll.get_version()
print "\nStep3, testing get_version_by_reference"
print '-'*80
vers = c_ulong(0x09)
print "before assigning...",vers.value
mydll.get_version_by_reference(vers)
print "after assigning...",vers.value
```

Hope it helps you to get started.

Comment: I tried the code but somehow it was not working according to what was needed in my code.